# Is there are better component to use rather than multiple diodes?

Tags: diodes, components, replacement

I am a long time computer programmer, but am fairly new at creating my own circuits.  The project I am working on currently is functioning properly, but I thought there may be a more elegant solution.

I am working on a circuit that will allow me to attach a NES Controller to the joystick port of an Atari or Commodore 64 without having to modify the NES Controller.  I do this by reading the NES controller with an Arduino and then "activating" the correct switches on the joystick port.

The Arduino pins are set as low input pins until they need to be activated.  When activated, they are set as output.  The pins are kept low all the time because if they are set high, they could damage the CIA chips in the Commodore.  To make sure that voltage is never applied to the CIA chip, I have placed 6 diodes in the circuit in the event that a pin is accidentally set high, it won't kill the CIA.  Five of those pins are for the controls (Up, Down, Left, Right, and Fire).  I am also pulling +5v from the Commodore port to power the Arduino through the RAW pin.  However, the RAW pin also gives +5v if the Arduino is powered through USB.  So, a sixth diode is used to keep that voltage from going back to the Commodore if the USB is connected.

Currently, I am using 1N4001 diodes.  My question is if there is something better / cheaper / easier to use than those diodes for this purpose?  Are these diodes too big for this circuit?  If so, what would be a better alternative?

Here is the schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please spend a little time discussing how you are using these I/O pins and how you've connected up the diodes. We'd also like to see what you are activating or driving. More information is lots better. Open your hand and let us see what you are about.

Comment: Also matters whether the connections are permanent or not and if not permanent if there is potential for misconnection.

Comment: If your objective is parts count and cost, diodes are real difficult to beat.

Comment: You are using diodes as reverse voltage protection. It sounds like your MCU pins are outputs to nodes that can also go high while your pins are low. Thats really the simplest way to protect the pins.

Comment: 1N4001 diodes are dog slow rectifier diodes. You might want to use something faster like a 1N4148, BAT54 etc.

Comment: Since there is nothing but a vague description what the diodes do in the circuit, we can't answer if they are even needed or not. Please provide schematics about the circuit and provide information what it does and what is the other device it connects to so we don't have to guess.

Comment: As kartman says there are better diodes to use for this task, they are also smaller and cheaper.

Comment: I have more throughly described what I am doing and have uploaded a schematic.

Answer (score 2):

1N4001 diodes are quite chunky rectifier diodes.  They should work fine, but are a bit over-the-top for your application.  On the plus side, they are extremely cheap.

If you want less voltage drop across the diodes, then Schottky diodes only drop about 0.2V, rather than 0.6V for a standard silicon diode.

If you want smaller diodes, then go for a small silicon signal diode, rather than a rectifier diode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. Just remove all the diodes, they are rather useless - just don't plug it via USB while it is connected to C64.

The MCU pins can be controlled to either pull down or float at high impedance by setting it as input (without pull-up being enabled).

Writing the MCU software so that there is no chance of mistakenly set a C64 port joystick pin as high output is trivial, so it should not require diodes at the joystick pins - a real joystick has no diodes either, just microswitches to pull these wires low.

Since a MCU like the AVR has built-in protection diodes, it means that the MCU should never be left unpowered while connected to C64, or the joystick pins try to feed power to MCU via the IO pins. External diodes also do not prevent this, as these also point towards the MCU.

So best thing is to power the MCU directly from C64, so that it always has power when connected to C64. It is also best done without the diode on the power pin. The diode will cause drop in the MCU supply voltage, let's assume 0.7V below the 5V supplied from C64. The joystick pins can reach the 5V logic level, but the MCU pins are not allowed to go more that 0.5V above MCU supply. So it could still try to suck power from the joystick data pins. Another thing is that since it is an AVR running at 16 MHz, it needs a supply voltage of at least 4.5V or the operation is not guaranteed.

So if protection is needed between MCU and C64 port, the diodes are not that great as I have described. Having a transistor (BJT or FET) there instead would make far better isolation, perhaps with some series resiators for limiting current, and it would make sense to slow down the AVR to 8 MHz to allow it to run much below 4.5V to make sure too low voltage at high frequency is not a cause of failure.

Comment: The chip (MOS 6562) that the OP wants to protect against *accidents* is becoming quite rare, so it seems to me that less than a dollar's-worth of diodes is a good investment.

Comment: @AndrewMorton OK, but setting a pin as high output is something that does not happen unless you write such code yourself. However, powering a 5V MCU via diode makes the MCU supply voltage to be much less than 5V, about 4.3V, so that has more implications than accidentally setting pin high. For instance, if it is a 16 MHz 5V Arduino Pro Micro, it is not specified to run below 4.5V, so basically the MCU does not have to work and it may execute wrong opcodes already. If it is a 8 MHz 3.3V Arduino Pro Micro, then it would anyway clamp the CIA matrix voltage even if there are protective diodes.